# Filter table in jQuery? or angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to be able to filter my table, the table is like this

```
name   |    date     |   agencyID
test      2016-03-17     91282774
test      2016-03-18     27496321
```

I want to be able to have a dropdown with all the 'agencyID' and when I select it only show the table rows with this agencyID in. I have a similar thing where you can search for anything in a input type text.

This is how that part works, is there any similar way I can do this with a select dropdown?

```
(function ($) {

    $('#filter').keyup(function () {

        var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.searchable tr').hide();
        $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();

    })

}(jQuery));
```

**I am open to implementing angularJS if this is a better alternative**

Comment: Take a look at [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

Comment: Is the rest your app already written in AngularJS? If so, yes, rewrite this as an AngularJS filter (and generally avoid depending on jQuery.) If not, then no, it wouldn't make sense to add Angular just for this one filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do an on change handler on the select drop down.

html:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<select id="filter">
  <option value="">Choose a filter</option>
  <option value="1231423424">1231423424</option>
  <option value="456456e54">456456e54</option>
  <option value="123488745">123488745</option>
</select>

<table id="searchable">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>agencyID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>date 1</td>
    <td>1231423424</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 2</td>
    <td>date 2</td>
    <td>456456e54</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 3</td>
    <td>date 3</td>
    <td>456456e54</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 4</td>
    <td>date 4</td>
    <td>123488745</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 5</td>
    <td>date 5</td>
    <td>123488745</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filter').change(function(){

    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    if(filterValue==""){
        $("#searchable tr").show();
    } else{
      $("#searchable tr").hide();
      $("#searchable td:nth-child(3)").each(function(){
        if( $(this).text() == filterValue){
          $(this).parent().show();
        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

[See it in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y30yzthz/)

Comment: Thank you, the fiddle was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation using :contains() selector

```
$select.on('change', function(){
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('table').find("tr:contains('"+id+"')").addClass('highlight');
  });
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9mzxxet4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can add to tr an id that is the agency

```
<select id="select">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="91282774">91282774</option>
<option value="27496321">27496321</option>
</select>

<table id="mytable">
<tr><th>name</th><th>data</th><th>agency</th></tr>
<tr id="91282774"><td>test</td><td>2016-03-17</td><td>91282774</td></tr>
<tr id="27496321"><td>test</td><td>2016-03-18</td><td>27496321</td></tr>
</table>
```

and search the id when change the selection

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#select").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == "")
        $("#mytable tr").show();
    else{
        $("#mytable tr[id=" + value + "]").show();
        $("#mytable tr[id][id!=" + value + "]").hide();
    }
  });

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59nr2om3/)